# php - right GET handling

Tags: php, security, get

I have file `users.php` and i want to display user's information when is set for example `users.php?id=5`

my "users.php" file is:

```
<?php 

$page_title = "Administrace - Uživatelé";
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/main.php");

if(!Admin::is_admin() or !User::is_logged()) // check if user is logged and is admin
{
    redirect($url."index.php"); //get out of here
}

$user = new User();

if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id = test_input($_GET["id"]); // = htmlspecialchars() & trim() & stripslashes()
    $is_valid = ctype_digit($id);
    if($is_valid && $user->check_user_available($id)) // check if $id is number AND if user with the $id is in database
    {
        // show user's information
    } else {
        // get out of here
        redirect($url."admin/");
    }
} else {

?>

        <i>...toto je random text...</i>

        <section>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Administrace -> Uživatelé</h1>
                <p>
                    <?php 
                    echo ($user->get_all_users()); // get all users (<a href="users.php?id=X">User</a>)
                    ?>
                </p>


            </div>
        </section>
            <aside>
            <?php
            $login = new Panel("login");
            $partneri = new Panel("partners");
            ?>
            </aside>


<?php  } require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template/footer.php");?>
```

my `check_user_availabe()` function:

```
<?php
public function check_user_available($id)
{
    $id = trim($id);
    $id = stripslashes($id);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($id);
    if(ctype_digit($id))
    {
        $query = Database::dotaz('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=?', array($id));
        if($query > 0)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm also using PDO prepared statements.. Here is my class `database` and `function dotaz()` (dotaz = query)

```
<?php
class Database {

    // Databázové spojení
    private static $connection;

    // Výchozí nastavení ovladače
    private static $nastaveni = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    );

    // Připojí se k databázi pomocí daných údajů
    public static function connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) {
        if (!isset(self::$connection)) {
            self::$connection = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",
                $username,
                $password,
                self::$nastaveni
            );
        }
    }
    public static function dotaz($dotaz, $parametry = array()) {
        $navrat = self::$connection->prepare($dotaz);
        $navrat->execute($parametry);
        return $navrat->rowCount();
    }?>
```

Could you say me if the $_GET part is well-secured or help me to secure it better ? Thank you all

Comment: Okay, so you use htmlspecialchars, stripslashes, etc.  But how does the User class handle it?

Comment: Edit your answer and put it there.   It looks like you're using a parameterized query, which is good.  But I still don't know what the Database class is.  With $_GET, you have to protect mainly against SQL injections by using prepared queries and XSS, cross site scripting, by disallowing code to be interpreted by the user's browser.

Comment: added.. hope it's what you mean

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to do the htmlspecialchars/stripslashes and everything for SQL, it looks like you are using prepared queries, so that will protect you.  htmlspecialchars and such is for XSS, but there are better ways.

Comment: ok, thanks.. i would be very grateful if you told me specific better ways, because im still learning and my priority is security

Comment: Spend an hour searching Stackoverflow for topics regarding SQL injection and XSS protection.  Learn about what you're doing, don't just do it blindly.

Comment: i know what i'm doing, but i dont know if there exists any better solution.
i was searching php security for more then 1 hour, but i think i need more

Comment: The rule is validate inputs, filter ouptuts. Here you want an int, validate that it's an int and reject the request if not. Then when you have an output filter accordingly (htmlspecialchars if the output is html, json_encode for json, filter sql for sql output, etc). Using filter functions on inputs wil lead you to errors, like double filtering. Keep it clear on validation/filters & in/out steps.